# Placing values(numbers) in a multilayers cell matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell, vectorization, cell-array, multi-layer

Assume Q is a matrix which has 3 cells and in each cell it has 2 other cells, means:

`Q={  { [] [] }   ; { [] [] }; { [] [] }  }`

Moreover, if we have **"a"** and **"b"** which they have 3 member each, and we would like to place

> **"a(1,1)"** into **"Q{1}{1}"**,
>
> **"b(1,1)"** into **"Q{1}{2}"**,
>
> **"a(2,1)"** into **"Q{2}{1}"**,
>
> **"b(2,1)"** into **"Q{2}{2}"**,
>
> **"a(3,1)"** into **"Q{3}{1}"**,
>
> **"b(3,1)"** into **"Q{3}{2}"**,

For example, if

```
a = [2; 3; 4];
b = [1; 5; 8]
```

Then Q should be like

```
Q={{2 1}; 
   {3 5}; 
   {4 8}}
```

Please note that we need a vectorized code and not a for-loop code as I already have the latter one, as shown next -

```
for i=1:size(Q,2)

     Q{i}{1}=a(i,:)
     Q{i}{2}=b(i,:)

end
```

Thanks.

Comment: And what's the problem with your loop?

Comment: I cleaned up your `Q` (keeping it structurally identical to how you had it) and it contradicts your loop which has cells in cells. Is there a reason to have the inner matrices as cells? i.e. can those scalars ever not be scalars? And also why not just `Q = [a,b]` and forget about cells?

Comment: How about this - `Q = mat2cell([a b].',2,ones(1,numel(a))).'`?

Comment: @Dan There is a reason to put each member inside of a  sub-cell matrix into each super-cell as I just simplified the Q, a, b matrices. Actually, Q and other matrices in my code have billions of numbers and each sub-cell represent a different characteristic.

Moreover, I would like to write it in line instead of loop as it can be very expensive and time consuming for such a huge data.

BTW, thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Divakar Many thanks. It looks very good. I was wondering if you could let me know how I can have each  **"a"** & **"b"** members into  separated cells. For example: `Q={{2}{1};{3}{5};{4}{8}}`

Comment: @Iman Maybe this - `mat2cell([a b].',[1 1],ones(1,numel(a))).'`

Comment: @Iman Have you tried preallocating `Q`?

Comment: @Divakar You're amazing man! That's the one!

If you could write your solution as a answer then I can mark it as final answer.

Comment: @Dan Yes, I did. But still this line should be faster than a loop. Am not 100% sure, I will apply it on my data and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dan I applied it for **100000** numbers. The loop were faster that the line:

`a=(1:100000)';
b=(1:100000)';`

`tic
Q=cell(size(a,1),1);
for  i=1:size(Q,1)
Q{i}{1}=a(i,:);
Q{i}{2}=b(i,:);
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.372703 seconds.`

`tic
Q=mat2cell(mat2cell([a b].',[1 1],ones(1,numel(a))).',ones(1,size(a,1)).');
toc
Elapsed time is 0.717828 seconds.`

Comment: @Iman Check out the edits in my solution, that includes benchmarking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Code**

```
Q = mat2cell(num2cell([a b]),ones(1,numel(a)),2)
```

---

## **Example**

**Code with input and output display**

```
a = [2; 3; 4]; %// Inputs
b = [1; 5; 8];

Q = mat2cell(num2cell([a b]),ones(1,numel(a)),2); %// Output

celldisp(Q) %// Display results
```

**Output on code run**

```
Q{1}{1} =
     2
Q{1}{2} =
     1
Q{2}{1} =
     3
Q{2}{2} =
     5
Q{3}{1} =
     4
Q{3}{2} =
     8
```

---

## **Benchmarking**

**Function for loop method**

```
function out = loop1(a,b)

out = cell(size(a,1),1); 
for i=1:size(out,1) 
    out{i}{1}=a(i,:); 
    out{i}{2}=b(i,:);
end

return;
```

**Function for vectorized method**

```
function out = vec1(a,b)

out = mat2cell(num2cell([a b]),ones(1,numel(a)),2);

return;
```

**Benchmarking Code**

```
N_arr = [50 100 200 500 1000 2000 5000 10000 50000]; %// array elements for N

timeall = zeros(2,numel(N_arr));
for k1 = 1:numel(N_arr)
    
    N = N_arr(k1);
    a = randi(9,N,1);
    b = randi(9,N,1);
    
    f = @() loop1(a,b);
    timeall(1,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f
    
    f = @() vec1(a,b);
    timeall(2,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f
end

%// Graphical display of benchmark results
figure,
hold on
plot(N_arr,timeall(1,:),'-ro')
plot(N_arr,timeall(2,:),'-kx')
legend('Loop Method','Vectorized Method')
xlabel('Datasize (N) ->'),ylabel('Time(sec) ->')
```

**Results**

[image]

**Conclusions**

Looks like vectorized method is the way to go, as it's showing almost double the performance (in terms of runtime) as compared to the loop approach across a wide range of datasizes.

Comment: This look great. I was just wondering how we can put each array into a cell? 
I mean instead of `Q = {{2}{1};{3}{5};{4}{8}}` it comes into  `Q = {{{2}{1}};{{3}{5}};{{4}{8}}}`

Comment: @Iman I am not sure how would you obtain or at least "picturise" - `Q = {{{2}{1}};{{3}{5}};{{4}{8}}}`? At least explain what is it?

Comment: Maybe further explanation would be helpful. I need **"Q"** in form of `Q={ {{}{}}; {{}{}}; {{}{}} }`. That's why it is named as a **multilayer** cell-matrix. It supposed to have 2 different depths.

Comment: @Iman See if this works - `mat2cell(mat2cell([a b],ones(1,numel(a)),[1 1]),[1 1 1],2)`?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I've just came to write. 


`Q=mat2cell(mat2cell([a b].',[1 1],ones(1,numel(a))).',ones(1,size(Q,1)).')`

Thanks a million ;)

Comment: Yes, That is great. I appreciate it. I have just updated your answer if it is OK for you.